# want to know when find command does not find anything

Tags: bash

Is there a way to have the find command return a value when it does not find a match?  Basically, I have an old backup, and I want to search for each of the files in it on my current computer.  Here is a cheesy way I was going to do it:

first run the following from the home directory:

```
$ ls -lR * > AllFiles.txt;
```

This will build my listing of all of my files on the current computer.

Next run the following script for each file in the back up:

```
#! /bin/bash
if ! grep $1 ~/AllFiles.txt; then
    echo file $1 not found;
    exit 1;
fi
```

Of course this is clunky, and it does not account for filename changes, but it's close enough.  Alternatively, I'd like to do a find command for each of the back up files.

Comment: Pass output through `grep .` If there was any output, grep would produce zero exit status, else non-zero.

Comment: Grep would work if you want your results slowed by 10x or more.

Comment: Ok, how about this then? `perl -e 'my $t=1; while(<>){$t=0;print;} exit $t;'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard return value test if using a standard gnu find, such as:

```
find . ! -readable -prune -o -name 'filenameToSearch.ext'
```

then check for return value using:

```
echo $?
```

if any value other than 0 means it did not find a match.

Comment: `EXIT STATUS
       find exits with status 0 if all files are processed successfully, greater than 0 if errors occur.   This is deliberately a very broad description, but if the return value  is  non-zero,
       you should not rely on the correctness of the results of find.` It does not say, if find actually found anything...

Comment: @anishsane, not true when searching for filenames. See man find for details.

Comment: $ `find . ! -readable -prune -o -name qkjfdqwuwqeqweqew;echo $?` Gave me `0`... find version: `find (GNU findutils) 4.4.2` Plus, I have not aliased it to anyting else.

Comment: I don't see anything about exit status based on whether a matching file was found or not: [manual link](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find). btw, my first comment was snippet from `man find`... `"if the return value is non-zero, you should not rely on the correctness of the results of find"` This implies that if `find` output is reliable, (i.e. it didn't find any matching files), then exit status is zero.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly;

```
grep -r valueORpatternToSearchinTEXT $(find . -type f) |wc -l
```

This will find for every file in the working/existing directory you are and its subdirs, search for what you need, then count for lines, if it is not found, you will get 0 at the end. Remove pipe and afterwards if you want to see what is found and where.